# Return corresponding date of max value

Tags: excel, matrix, indexing, max, match

I'm looking for a formula which will give me the date of the last version of the order.
To illustrate, the sheet looks as follows:

```
  A               B               C
1 Sales Order     Version         Date
2 SO#12345        1               21/02/2013
2 SO#12345        2               28/04/2013
3 SO#12345        3               04/08/2013
4 SO#12345        4               27/09/2013
5 SO#54321        1               02/03/2014
6 SO#54321        2               31/03/2014
7 SO#54321        3               07/10/2014
8 SO#54321        4               13/12/2014
```

So I would like to get the date of SO#12345, version 4 (29/09/2013).

I've tried several combinations of INDEX, MATCH, IF and MAX functions, but I can't seem to get the right value.

It either gives me the corresponding date of the highest value  in the version column or it gives me the correct version number, but I can't make it show the appropriate date.

I did use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER for these formulas, so they are executed as a matrix function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, assuming the *Order Number* is in E2, try:

`=LOOKUP(1,0/FREQUENCY(0,1/(1+(A2:A8=E2)*B2:B8)),C2:C8)`

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If the versions are listed in order for each Sales Order numberyou can use `LOOKUP` like this:

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(A$2:A$8=E2),C$2:C$8)`

Where E2 contains a specific order number

....or you can use the order number directly

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(A$2:A$8="SO#12345"),C$2:C$8)`

Comment: Unfortunately it's not always sorted this neatly, so I really do need the version column to determine the correct date.