# mysql Max(date) value in returned rows

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, max, greatest-n-per-group

in mytable when i query

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE adsh='0000002178-18-000009' and tag='assets'
```

i get this result

`adsh                 tag    ddate      value`
`0000002178-18-000009 Assets 2016-12-31 246872000.00`
`0000002178-18-000009 Assets 2017-12-31 282704000.00`

**but i wish to have only the row containing the max(ddate) returned, the 2017-12-31 row** Note there are many other different tags. But since the table holds >100k rows i wish to make sure i am doing the right query before expanding it to all rows.

I tried many different queries & variations but no cigar :/

```
SELECT *,max(ddate) FROM mytable WHERE adsh='0000002178-18-000009' and tag='Assets'
```

that return the wrong line

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE ddate = (select max(ddate) and adsh='0000002178-18-000009' and tag='Assets' from mytable)
```

that returns 0 rows

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE ddate = (select max(ddate) and adsh='0000002178-18-000009' and tag='Assets' from mytable)
```

that returns 0 rows

```
SELECT DISTINCT adsh,tag,ddate,value from mytable
WHERE ddate = (select max(ddate) from mytable) group by adsh
```

but that's not returning what i expect either

Does anyone have a idea how i can acheive this ?

Thanks a million :)

Comment: For one definite tag use simple ```SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE adsh='0000002178-18-000009' AND tag='assets' ORDER BY dddate DESC LIMIT 1```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
select * 
from mytable
where ddate = (
    select max(ddate) 
    from mytable
    where adsh='0000002178-18-000009' and tag='Assets' 
)
```

You would get something more accurate by repeating the conditions in the `where` clause of the outer query:

```
select * 
from mytable
where adsh = '0000002178-18-000009' and tag = 'Assets'  and ddate = (
    select max(ddate) 
    from mytable
    where adsh = '0000002178-18-000009' and tag = 'Assets' 
)
```

Just in case, let me pinpoint that if you are sure that are no top ties, this can be simpler done with `limit`:

```
select * 
from mytable
where adsh = '0000002178-18-000009' and tag = 'Assets'
order by dddate desc limit 1
```

Finally: if you are running MySQL 8.0, you can also use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        rank() over(order by ddate desc) as rn
    from mytable t
    where adsh = '0000002178-18-000009' and tag = 'Assets'
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, i was able to figure it out with the help of this post :) [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28563100/return-corresponding-date-of-max-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28563100/return-corresponding-date-of-max-value)